# Having trouble with next/Image component centering/covering it's parent div when Header/Footer layout components are added

Tags: css, next.js, flexbox, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

Home page in NextJS, styled with TailwindCSS, is working as expected.  I originally had the background image defined in the `tailwind.config.js` file and applied via styles (and there is no problem), but I would prefer the image optimization of `next/Image`.

```
// index.jsx

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-center py-0">
      <Image src='/images/background.png' fill={true} style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }} className='-z-10' alt='Alt text' />
      <main className='flex w-full flex-1 flex-col items-center justify-center px-5 md:px-20 text-center bg-gradient-radial to-r from-black via-black/30'> {/* All content here is displaying as expected */} </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This works as expected.  But, when I add an overall `Layout.jsx` to the site, the background image alignment is not behaving as I would anticipate.

```
// Layout.jsx

import Navbar from './Navbar.jsx'
import Footer from './Footer.jsx'

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <main>
                {children}
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </> 
    )
}

export default Layout
```

The `background.png` image no longer aligns with its parent `<div>`, but instead with the top of the screen.  This means the navbar is sitting on top of the background image, obstructing some of the top portion.

Simultaneously, a gap now exists between the bottom of the background image and the top of the Footer, equal in height to the height of the Navbar.

I have tried all combinations of `relative` and `absolute` classes both the parent `<div>` and the child `<Image>`, without success.

Switching back to a `tailwind.config.js` defined background image and inserting it using e.g. `className='bg-my_bg_image'` solves the alignment issues, but no longer leverages NextJS `next/Image` optimization and hurts my site performance.

So the preferred solution would be to continue to use the `next/Image` component, aligned properly.